# Extracting and Printing Table Headers and Data with Beautiful Soup with Python 2.7

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-table

So I'm trying to scrape data from the table on the [Michigan Department of Health and Human Services website](https://www.mdch.state.mi.us/osr/natality/BirthsTrends.asp) using BeautifulSoup 4.0 and I don't know how to format it properly.

I have the code below written to get the  and  information from the website but I'm at a loss as how to format it so that it has the same appearance as the table on the website when I print it or save it as a .txt/ .csv file. I've looked around here and on a bunch of other websites for an answer but I'm not sure how to go forward with this. I'm very much a beginner so any help would be appreciated.

My code just prints a long list of either the table rows or table data:

```
import urllib2
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mdch.state.mi.us/osr/natality/BirthsTrends.asp"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup((page), "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table")
rows = table.find_all("tr")

for tr in rows:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print tds
```

The HTML that I'm looking at is below as well:

```
<table border=0 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 width=640  align="center">
  <thead style="display: table-header-group;"> 
  <tr height=18  align="center"> 
     <th height=35 align="left" colspan="2">County</th>

     <th height="35" align="right">
     2005
     </th>
```

that part shows the years as headers and goes until 2015 and then the state and county data is further down:

```
   <tr height="40" > 
      <th class="LeftAligned" colspan="2">Michigan</th>
 <td>
 127,518
 </td>
```

and so on for the rest of the counties.
Again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: All you have to do is make a multidimensional array ( row -> columns ) and you are ok.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here, but how would I go about doing that as far as the code goes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store your table in a list

```
import urllib2
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mdch.state.mi.us/osr/natality/BirthsTrends.asp"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup((page), "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table")
rows = table.find_all("tr")

table_contents = []   # store your table here
for tr in rows:
    if rows.index(tr) == 0 : 
        row_cells = [ th.getText().strip() for th in tr.find_all('th') if th.getText().strip() != '' ]  
    else : 
        row_cells = ([ tr.find('th').getText() ] if tr.find('th') else [] ) + [ td.getText().strip() for td in tr.find_all('td') if td.getText().strip() != '' ] 
    if len(row_cells) > 1 : 
        table_contents += [ row_cells ]
```

Now `table_contents` has the same structure and data as the table on the page.

Comment: Ok. I see how that works. So now that I have a bunch of nested lists, I can pretty much split that first list with the state and county names and assign them to the "0" position for their respective lists in the group and then strip all the extra \r\n and \xa0 code out. Does that make sense?
 That way it would read: [County, 2005, 2006....2015] and so on.

Comment: Yes, thats pretty much it.   As i said the `table_contents` has the same structure and content as the table on the website, you can process it however you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll explore the options. Right now I have `table_headers = table_contents[0]` and `table_body = table_contents[1:99]` which seem to separate it fine. I also noticed at the end of the output that "Detroit City" and "Wayne ExcludingDetroit" are already in the list with their table values. Any idea why that happened?

Comment: For some reason i can't access the website.  If you post your output, i could take a look.

Comment: The output at the end looks like this `[u'', u'Detroit City', u'13,156', u'13,002', u'12,126', u'11,791', u'11,180', u'10,941', u'10,338', u'10,081', u'10,123', u'9,818', u'9,891'], [u'', u'Wayne ExcludingDetroit', u'14,216', u'14,309', u'14,230', u'13,833', u'13,467', u'13,228', u'13,388', u'13,028', u'13,489', u'13,548', u'13,581']`

Comment: Have you modified the code ? Have you modified `table_contents` ? Is this the output of `table_body` ?  How is the table on the website formated ( <tr><th></th></tr>, <tr><td><td></tr>, ... ) ?

Comment: The code is still the same as above. The format is `</tr>
 <tr height=17> 
    <td height=17 class="sansRightBorder" width="5">&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap height=17 class="sansLeftBorder" >Wayne Excluding<br>Detroit</td> <td valign="top" class="Reducedtd">
14,216
</td>`. That's really the only thing that I've noticed though. The rest of it  looks all right.

Comment: That seems to be a classic html table, with the first row having the headers ( th ), and the rest having columns ( td ). If so, your code should be fine, you have the headers here : `table_headers = table_contents[0]` ( first row ) and the rest here : `table_body = table_contents[1:99]` ( all the rest ) .  You may want to get rid of the empty cells though. Change htis line : `table_contents += [ [ td.getText().strip() for td in tr.find_all('td') ] ]` to this : `table_contents += [ [ td.getText().strip() for td in tr.find_all('td') if td.getText().strip() != '&nbsp;' ] ]`

Comment: So I made those changes and it stripped out the empty lists for the headers but it left the lists in the body that look like `[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']`. Any thoughts on how to get rid of those? In the HTML they're just the footers that make the table look fancier.

To clarify, my code now looks like:
`for tr in rows:
    table_contents += [ [ td.getText().strip() for td in tr.find_all('td') if td.getText().strip() != '&nbsp;' ] ]`

Comment: Ok, i managed to access the site with tor ( ??? ) , and i can see the table. The problem is that  all 'County' rows are table headers except 'Detroit City' and 'Wayne Excluding Detroit' , because they are subsets of 'Wayne' .  I modified the code, it should be ok now.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! Thank you again for the help. I'd be lost in the sauce without you.